# Oracle query to list all parents before children

Tags: oracle, parent, children

I have a table which has `child#`, `parent#` like the following :

```
child# |  parent#
------------------
10     | NULL
20     | NULL
2      | 1
1      | 10 
50     | 10
6      | 5 
5      | 2
```

There is no ordering of numbers, i.e. 1 can be parent of 10 and 10 can be parent of 20.

I want an ORACLE SQL query which lists all parents first, followed by their children.

I want a temporary table like following:

```
child# | parent#
----------------
10     | NULL
20     | NULL
1      | 10
2      | 1 
50     | 10
5      | 2
```

I want to traverse this temporary table and process each rows, so for that I need to make sure parent is listed before the children rows.

Comment: Google `START WITH CONNECT BY` - sounds like that's what you're looking for

Comment: No, i tried all variants of connect by clause but its not solving the problem. Probably it can be solved with connect by clause but i am not able to solve it.

Comment: I don't understand what you want. Should the result from the query look like the 2nd table?

Comment: alfasin is right about using `CONNECT BY START WITH PRIOR`. I don't think you will need anything else.

Comment: Yes, the result of query should look like 2nd table.

Comment: I don't have any level column in the table. If i execute the query select group#, parent# from ols$groups start with parent# is null connect by prior group#=parent#; i am getting the following result

    GROUP#    PARENT#
---------- ----------
        10 
         1         10
         0          1
         5          0
         6          5
         2          1
         3          1
        50         10
        10
         1         10
         0          1
....

Comment: @user2783058 the `level` is not a column, check out the link to the fiddle I posted in my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select level,child,parent
from your_table
start with t2.parent is null
connect by prior t2.child = t2.parent
order by level
```

**OUTPUT**:

```
LEVEL   CHILD   PARENT
1       10      (null)
1       20      (null)
2       1       10
2       50      10
3       2       1
4       5       2
5       6       5
```

Link to *[fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/d9a28/1)*